# Java: Static access using a string?

Tags: java, string, static

Wasnt too sure on the title for the but I have a file that is used to retrieve certain texture coordinates. The file is called Assets and just contains a bunch of items like what is below...

```
public static TextureRegion level1;
```

To get access to this I just use Assets.level1 for another part of the program and thats that.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to do this through a string, for example instead of Assets.level2 i could do something like Assets.(string) where string = "level2"

Any help will be great

Comment: You probably could in that specific scenario using a getter or reflection. How about HashMapping your TextureRegions to string keys in a map? String for a key, TextureRegion for a value?

Comment: Not in Java. You can in Groovy and other languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(TextureRegion)Assets.class.getField("level2").get(null)`

Comment: this works well it just throws a lot of exceptions which need surrounded with try catch's

Answer (score 4):

Instead of having those as static fields in the `Assets` class, you should add a static method to `Assets`:

```
public static TextureRegion getTextureRegion(String name)
{
    // get it somehow
}
```

Now, for the "somehow" part: the easiest (and most flexible) way would be to have a `Map<String, TextureRegion>` (`Map` is an interface, `HashMap` would probably be sufficient in this case) in your `Assets` class that contains the texture regions. How you put data in that map is up to you. For instance:

```
regions.put("level1", your_level_1_region);
```

Then, your `getTextureRegion` becomes:

```
public static TextureRegion getTextureRegion(String name)
{
    return regions.get(name);
}
```

The upside of this is that those regions could be determined at runtime (perhaps loaded from a file) instead of being hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

You can access static fields of a class based on a variable by using the Java Reflection API.

```
TextureRegion lvl = (TextureRegion) Assets.class.getDeclaredField("level1").get(null);
```